# Make a executable kivy file for Windows, problem with pyinstaller

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, pyinstaller, sdl-2

There are 4 files in my directory:

1. `kv` file
2. `py` file
3. SQLite database
4. `py` file which I'm importing into the `py(2)` file

When I use `pyinstaller --onefile main.py` it creates an `.exe` file. When I run this file in the console, it prints out: `No such file in directory: 'struct.kv'` (my kv file).

I want to add it in a spec file. I write `from kivy.deps import sdl2, glew` on 2 lines and:

```
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          [Tree(p) for p in (sdl2.dep_bins + glew.dep_bins)],
```

and all that goes on in datas: `datas=[ ( '/src/struct.kv', '.' )]`.
But when I try `pyinstaller main.spec` I got this warning:

```
502 WARNING: stderr:     exec(text, spec_namespace)
File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
504 WARNING: stderr:   File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'sdl2'
509 WARNING: stderr: ImportError: cannot import name 'sdl2'
```

Why can't I import?

Comment: Do you have `from kivy.deps import sdl2, glew` somewhere in your code that pyinstaller can pick up?

Comment: you should not have to bundle it in with tree ... just add that import(see @CoryKramer) to the top of your main entry point

Comment: @CoryKramer ok, on first line in my main py file i added `from kivy.deps import sdl2, glew` and when making spec file, added this line in spec file too, add `[Tree(p) for p in (sdl2.dep_bins + glew.dep_bins)]` is that right?